# Writing into a File using a Try Except Loop always results in the except block

Tags: python, file, try-except

The function should open the file and if an exception occurs the function should display an error message and the function should return None. If an exception does not occur while opening, the code should write into the file text.

```py
def write_string(fname, text):
    try:
        f = open(fname, 'r')
        f.read()
        l = open(fname, 'w')
        return l.write(text)
    except:
        print(f'Error occurred when opening {fname} to read')
        return None
```

However, it seems to always return an error and never actually write the file. Any advice? I'm still new to Python.

When testing it I get this:
Full printing (excluding input prompts/lines and empty lines) should look something like:

```
"""
The following (excluding input prompts/lines and empty lines) was printed:
"""
Error occurred when opening basic_io.write_string_0.txt to read
Error occurred when opening basic_io.write_string_0.txt to read
```

Comment: If you catch all exceptions without printing detailed error messages, you loose important information about the error. Only catch specific expected exception(s) and/or use `traceback.print_exc` to print the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Can you include the exception you get? You can print the exception you are getting in the except block or remove the `try:` and `except` for now.

Comment: Why are you reading the file at all?  You're throwing away any data that was read, so all this accomplishes is to make it necessary for the file to already exist.  If you only wrote to the file, this code would work anyway, creating the file if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's bad practice to catch *all* exceptions -- you should catch the specific exceptions that you know how to handle (for example, `FileNotFoundError` is a specific exception you might encounter when trying to open a file), and let others raise.  That will make your program easier to debug when you encounter unexpected exceptions, because Python will automatically halt the program and print an error message that tells you *exactly* what exception was raised and *where*, instead of putting you in the situation where you're getting an error message but have no idea what's causing it.

If you are going to broadly catch exceptions and print an error message, you should strongly consider printing the error message that's contained in the exception itself:

```
def write_string(fname, text):
    try:
        f = open(fname, 'r')
        f.read()
        l = open(fname, 'w')
        return l.write(text)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error occurred when opening {fname} to read: {e}')
        return None
```

This will probably give you something to go on.

Note that the `except` will catch *any* error that happens in the `try` block, not just the `open(fname, 'r')` call!  So the error you're printing is misleading -- it might not necessarily be something that's happening because you opened the file to read.  For example, if I run the above version of the function with a read-only file, I get:

```
>>> write_string("foo.txt", "asdfasdf")
Error occurred when opening foo.txt to read: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'foo.txt'
```

If I simply remove the `try/except` the error is more informative:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    write_string("foo.txt", "asdfasdf")
  File "test.py", line 4, in write_string
    l = open(fname, 'w')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'foo.txt'
```

because now I can see that I'm getting a `PermissionError` and that it happened on the `open(fname, 'w')` call, i.e. my attempt to open the file for *write*, not read.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any argument to the write function which expects a single argument.

```
def write_string(fname, text):
    try:
        f = open(fname, 'r')
        f.read()
        l = open(fname, 'w')
        return l.write(text)
    except:
        print(f'Error occurred when opening {fname} to read')
        return None
```

should work.

Also, IN YOUR CASE, I would recommend using:-

```
try:
    # Do something
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

to print the error message.

But generally, as [@michael-butscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987358/michael-butscher) pointed out, it is better to "catch specific expected expections".